# how to fix CERT_HAS_EXPIRED error with node-fetch inside docker container with debian 8, related to Lets Encrypt DST_Root_CA_X3 cert

Tags: node.js, docker, meteor, debian, lets-encrypt

I have an old application built with meteor 8, running in a node v8.11.4 docker image, since September 31 throwing `CERT_HAS_EXPIRED` error.

Tried different combinations of ignoring the DST_ROOT_CA_X3 and deleting it, then downloading it but still getting the same error while making requests to lioren.io, which has a let's encrypt issued SSL certificate.

Commands tried:

```
RUN sed -i 's#mozilla\/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt#!mozilla\/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt#g' /etc/ca-certificates.conf 

RUN update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

Debian version:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

So, how can I fix this cert error, should maybe try another base image?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the server that has an old certificate with an expired root CA (this is a Let's Encrypt problem).

See:

https://www.catchpoint.com/blog/lessons-from-an-internet-outage-issues-caused-by-lets-encrypt-dst-root-ca-x3-expiration

https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/